# "Required entry point * never provided" when compiling play application

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0, requirejs, google-closure-compiler

For the past couple of days I've been trying to minify a project that I've been working on.

The project uses Play 2.1.2 and a variety of javascript libraries, namely jquery, jquery_ui, kendo, and jQuery. Initially, all of the javascript files were located in the public/javascripts directory and everything worked fine. From what I read, for Google Closure Compiler to do its job the files need to be located in the app/assets/javascripts directory.

I moved the files to app/assets/javascripts and when I attempted to compile it errored with the following for jquery, jquery_ui, kendo, knockout, and jQuery.

`[error] c.g.j.jscomp - ERROR - required entry point "module$insertnamehere" never provided`

So far, I've tried changing the javascriptEntryPoints key in Build.scala to point to the libraries. I've also tried changing the key to include a js file which sets the path definition for the libraries which looks like

```
require.config({
    'urlArgs': 'v=3.1.0',
    'paths': {
        'jquery-ui': 'libs/jquery-ui.min',
        'ko': 'libs/knockout',
        'underscore': 'libs/lodash.min',
        'kendo': 'libs/kendo/kendo.all.min',
        'messages': '../messages',
        'waitSeconds': 200
    },
    'shim': {
        'ko': {
            'exports': 'ko'
        },
        'underscore': {
            'exports': '_'
        },
        'kendo': {
            'exports': 'kendo'
        }
    },
    'baseUrl': '/assets/javascripts'
});
```

None of what I have tried so far has had an effect on the error messages.
Are there any additional steps that I should be taking? How and where do I provide these entry points?

I am new to the team and haven't had any prior experience in web development so it's a bit overwhelming. Any help would be appreciated.